# Why is import cats.implicits._ no longer necessary for importing type class instances?

Tags: scala, import, typeclass, implicit, scala-cats

In Cats 2.1.x type class instances were brought in scope with `import cats.implicits._`

```
scala> import cats.Show
import cats.Show

scala> Show[Int].show(42)
<console>:13: error: could not find implicit value for parameter instance: cats.Show[Int]
       Show[Int].show(42)
           ^

scala> import cats.implicits._
import cats.implicits._

scala> Show[Int].show(42)
res1: String = 42
```

however in Cats [2.2.0](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2djZTSi9S92SNJb1crzTkw) it works without `import cats.implicits._` for example

```
scala> import cats.Show
import cats.Show

scala> Show[Int].show(42)
val res0: String = 42
```

What changed and how should we use imports from now on?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I thought it would be useful to record it in SO. I could answer it but maybe someone else would like to give it a go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2.1.x instances of type classes were defined in separate objects so in order to be in scope (local scope) they had to be imported

```
object implicits extends instances.AllInstances with ...

trait AllInstances extends AnyValInstances with ...

trait AnyValInstances extends IntInstances with ...

trait IntInstances extends cats.kernel.instances.IntInstances {
  implicit val catsStdShowForInt: Show[Int] = Show.fromToString[Int]
}
```

In 2.2.0 instances of type classes are defined in companion objects so they are in scope (implicit scope) automatically and do not have to be imported

```
object Show extends ScalaVersionSpecificShowInstances with ShowInstances {
  ...
  implicit def catsShowForInt: Show[Int] = cats.instances.int.catsStdShowForInt
  ...
}
```

Release notes https://github.com/typelevel/cats/releases/tag/v2.2.0

> In most cases all that's necessary to switch to using the new implicit scope instances is to replace `cats.implicits._` imports with `cats.syntax.all._` and delete any `cats.instances` imports. You don't have to make this change to use Cats 2.2.x, though, since this release doesn't remove anything. Importing `cats.implicits._` will do exactly the same thing on Cats 2.1.x and 2.2.x, since imported instances have higher priority than implicit scope. You just won't see improvements in compile times.
>
> There is one exception to this rule. The `cats.implicits` package provides implicit conversions from Cats's own `Order` and `PartialOrder` type classes to the standard library's `Ordering` and `PartialOrdering`. This conversion is not available in implicit scope, because it would be a bad idea for Cats to put instances of type classes it doesn't own into scope for types that it doesn't own (and also because it's not possible).

[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html